# Does decimal in cache version break service worker

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

Have a question guys. I noticed the cache version used in the service worker is used to populate the App Details page in Android following the new A2HS experience. 
I have a working service worker but recently decided to update the version from v1 to v1.2 and everything broke, I basically had to clear site storage from devmode. 
So, does the decimal, break versioning of service worker or something else must have happened. By something else I mean, I was toggling between network modes while refreshing the new install.

Comment: This sounds super strange. What do you mean by updating your version number? You updated a string literal, right? Could you share some code in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version number should be a String that is declared at the start of your service worker file, and as such the decimal should have no impact on the rest of your code.

Versioning in Service Workers just simpily compares the name (String Value) of the version attribute in your code Vs. the name (String Value) of the active cache.

As long as you have correctly implemented event.waitUntil() on your install event, there should not be a problem between toggling network modes and refreshing.

Comment: Right. Thanks, I guess something else must have gone wrong. I'm very new to Service Workers so I'm hitting some bumps.

Comment: Was new to them myself about a month ago, so I can see where you are coming from. Takes a bit to wrap your head around the lifecycle! Could you accept my answer please? :)

Comment: Absolutely. If you don't mind helping with one more thing. I added my service worker to the list of assets to cache, would this affect the getting of the next version when next I publish files. I'd assume the service worker is called from the register script in the index and not via url but I may be wrong

Comment: While I am open to being corrected on this, my believing is that caching your service worker file should not have any affect on an update. You are correct in saying the service worker is called from the register script, and the install event is only fired once per Service Worker - The browser considers any change in the Service Worker code as a new Service Worker. This means that upon update, the register script will point the browser towards the new Service Worker and the Install event will fire!